# data.table::fread adds an empty column

Tags: r, data.table, fread, is-empty

I am using the data.table package to read in a file with following data:

```
Date        Time    S1      S2      S3
1/1/2014    0:01:00 92.73   483.73  135.18997
2/1/2014    0:01:00 102.73  581.73  166.25931
...
```

Separated by either tabs or commas. Using fread I get:

```
DT <- fread("data1.txt",stringsAsFactors = FALSE,colClasses = "character",header =T)
> DT
        Date       Time     S1      S2         S3  V4
 1: 1/1/2014    0:01:00  92.73  483.73  135.18997
 2: 2/1/2014    0:01:00 102.73  581.73  166.25931
```

It adds an empty column V4 because of the presence of tabs in the end of each line in the data1.txt file. I can remove this empty column but I want to know if there is a way to stop fread from doing this?

Comment: Can't reproduce with that example.  But you could probably use `select = 1:5`

Comment: Thanks. But the number of columns as well as rows are not fixed in the files I read. Also, empty columns may not always be in the end. Attaching the example file for reproduction.

Comment: I'll go out on a limb: There's no way to stop the empty columns from being read, since there's no way to know whether they are truly empty until they are fully processed. Assigning classes to columns is a similar issue. The `read` functions make a good guess based on the first few rows of data and potentially make corrections when an anomaly is detected.

Comment: But the thing is, that there is no empty column in the file. Just some extra tabs (mostly) at the end. There is a way to skip empty rows I wish we could do the same with columns. If the file is large (for me it runs in millions of lines), then reading in empty columns is just an unnecessary burden on RAM.

Comment: @RichScriven:Could'nt find a way to attach a file, here is a line to reproduce the data1.txt: `sink("data1.txt"); cat("Date\tTime\tS1\tS2\tS3\t\n1/1/2014\t0:01:00\t92.73\t483.73\t135.18997\t\n2/1/2014\t0:01:00\t102.73\t581.73\t166.25931\t"); sink()`

Comment: If it is consistently the case that you have one more field than you would like, you can read in the first (10) lines using the `nrows=10` argument, count the number of columns, and then tell fread to  ignore the last column with the drop argument.

Comment: "But the thing is, that there is no empty column in the file. Just some extra tabs (mostly) at the end." That's a contradiction. If your file is tab delimited and you have extra tabs, you have empty columns. Just read in as is and remove empty columns afterwards.

Comment: I understand what you mean. C1,C2,,C3 = 4 columns. I was hoping there was a way of telling fread it's only 3. Anyway, Thank you all for your comments at least I now know that removing empty columns is the only option. Thanks :)